# RegEx is Malforming My JSON

Tags: php, regex, json

Well this is unusual. I have the following JSON file:

#### settings.json

```
{
    "somekey":"someval",
    "regexes":{
        "url":"/([^\/]+)(?:\/\(([^\)]+)\))?\/?([\S]+)?/"
    }
}
```

#### PHP

`var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('settings.json'),true))` is returning `null` with a `json_last_error()` saying I have malformed JSON.

I've been checking to see if it doesn't like some of the characters in my regex... deleting random bits and checking... sometimes it returns my JSON object, sometimes it returns `null`, but I can't seem to narrow down anything. What am I missing here?

Comment: I suppose this is one of the items on the list of reasons that returning a normal PHP array is preferred for configuration.

Comment: As opposed to a stdClass object? Yeah, I was working with objects at first, then I came across a setting with a dash ("some-setting"), which doesn't work with objects: `$settings->some-setting`... so had to rewrite everywhere I referenced that stdClass to convert to array: `$settings['some-setting']`

Comment: You could have done what you wanted like `$settings->{"some-setting"}`.

Comment: @Marty sweet! I couldn't figure out the syntax for that... thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes must be escaped in JSON. This is valid:

```
{
    "somekey":"someval",
    "regexes":{
        "url":"/([^\\/]+)(?:\\/\\(([^\\)]+)\\))?\\/?([\\S]+)?/"       
    }
}
```

The output of your `var_dump` would then be:

```
array(2) {
  ["somekey"]=>
  string(7) "someval"
  ["regexes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(40) "/([^\/]+)(?:\/\(([^\)]+)\))?\/?([\S]+)?/"
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Is it JSON that doesn't like single backslashes, or the json_decode function?

Comment: It's a [JSON thing](http://json.org/), the JSON in your file was invalid without escaping the backslashes. This also applies to many (most?) other languages, including PHP. The reason that @flec suggested four slashes is because in PHP, each backslash must be escaped, so you get left with two for every four. The resulting string that is parsed by `json_decode` is the same for both our answers.

Answer (score 1):

For every backslash you want to print as a backslash you need four backslashes. Therefore the following gives your expected Result:

```
<?php 
    $json = '{
        "somekey":"someval",
        "regexes":{
            "url":"/([^\\\\/]+)(?:\\\\/\\\\(([^\\\\)]+)\\\\))?\\\\/?([\\\\S]+)?/"
        }
    }';

    var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["somekey"]=>
  string(7) "someval"
  ["regexes"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(40) "/([^\/]+)(?:\/\(([^\)]+)\))?\/?([\S]+)?/"
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, but it seems two backslashes output one backslash